# how to print the range of sequence number

Tags: unix, awk, sed, perl-module

Hi friends i have a list of non sequential numbers in a file, need to list sequential range of number.

example:

```
641
642
643
712
713
714
813
814
815
```

need to print:

```
641-643,712-714,813-815
```

either in awk,unix or perl

Comment: what did you try? it is important to show your attempts

Comment: My colleague is working on such file , hence its my duty to help him.

Comment: You should first show us what you have tired, so that we can help you out in the right direction by pointing out any mistakes you made during the aproach and any better aproaches.

Comment: it is in fact an interesting problem. It would be good if you could show what you have tried and where were you stuck.  Question like "I have this, I want to have that, do it for me please" is not welcomed here. That might be the reaseon why you got so many downvotes. But again, I think this is an interesting problem. @MaheshCholleti next time try asking in a better way.

Comment: We are trying to help, only that we appreciate people following the suggestions given in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks Kent for suggestions, next time i will have a good approach.

Comment: @TomFenech it is not a dup, is it? I would say, "similar question"

Comment: @fedorqui bro sorry i was liitle bit harsh.

Answer (score 1):

this line works for your example:

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "%s",$0;p=$0;next}
     $0!=p+1{printf "-%d %d",p,$0}{p=$0}END{print "-"$0}' f
```

with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
641
642
643
712
713
714
813
814
815
kent$   awk 'NR==1{printf "%s",$0;p=$0;next}$0!=p+1{printf "-%d %d",p,$0}{p=$0}END{print "-"$0}' f
641-643 712-714 813-815
```

Note that the last group number may have problem (with unexpected `-` ) It depends on your input. Anyway, you got the idea, you can do something adjustment on the line above.